# How to use a query to get the definition of (MariaDB 10.3.27) database objects (specifically the variables they use)

Tags: mariadb, information-schema, mariadb-10.3

I have written a query to get most of the useful information about the routines in a MariaDB database for a database documenter that I am developing.

The code below will return routine name, routine type, routine param list, routine return value (if any), routine definition and routine comment (if any).

However I can't seem to work out how to return any variables that are used by each routine (either local or system)

Can anyone help me out with the code to get that extra column displayed in my query with the variable names in it?
(Be good if they were concatenated as I have done with the parameters but that's not too important.)

As an example, below is the definition of a function that uses the variable "result".  (Other routines may have more than one though or even use system variables such as `version`). I want to get another column in my query that shows, in this case, `name_to_use VARCHAR(50)`.

If there are more than one variable, then maybe `concat` them to have the column contain something like

```
name_to_use VARCHAR(50); IDnumber INT; JoinDate DATETIME; TheAmount decvimal(10,2)
```

etc.

These variable names and the routine they are used in  may held in a system table somewhere, if so I don't know where or I may have to parse the definition SQL, if so I'm not sure how. This is what IO would appreciate some help with
*I would stress that the databases are held on a remote shared server so I cannot log in as root, nor can I access it as local host. ie for example, access to tables like 'proc' and 'users' and others that would be available to an admin user are denied*

**The code I have so far that returns most of the information** (also included in case it's useful to anyone else)

```
SELECT routine_name, routine_type, routine_param_list,routine_returns,routine_body, routine_comment FROM (

SELECT
  
    `information_schema`.`events`.`EVENT_NAME` AS `routine_name`,
    'EVENT' AS `routine_type`,
    '' AS `routine_param_list`,
    '' AS `routine_returns`,
    `information_schema`.`events`.`EVENT_DEFINITION` AS `routine_body`,
    `information_schema`.`events`.`EVENT_COMMENT` AS `routine_comment`

  FROM
    `information_schema`.`events`
   
    
    
  UNION
  ALL
  
  SELECT
   
    `information_schema`.`routines`.`ROUTINE_NAME` AS `routine_name`,
    `information_schema`.`routines`.`ROUTINE_TYPE` AS `routine_type`,
    (SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
          `information_schema`.`parameters`.`PARAMETER_MODE`,
          ' ',
          `information_schema`.`parameters`.`PARAMETER_NAME`,
          ' ',
          `information_schema`.`parameters`.`DTD_IDENTIFIER`
        ) SEPARATOR '; '
      )
    FROM
      `information_schema`.`parameters`
    WHERE `information_schema`.`parameters`.`SPECIFIC_NAME` = `information_schema`.`routines`.`ROUTINE_NAME`
    GROUP BY `information_schema`.`parameters`.`SPECIFIC_NAME`) AS `routine_param_list`,
    `information_schema`.`routines`.`DTD_IDENTIFIER` AS `routine_returns`,
    `information_schema`.`routines`.`ROUTINE_DEFINITION` AS `routine_body`,
    `information_schema`.`routines`.`ROUTINE_COMMENT` AS `routine_comment`

  FROM
    `information_schema`.`routines`
   

    UNION
    ALL
    
    (SELECT
      
      `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_NAME` AS `routine_name`,
      `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_TYPE` AS `routine_type`,
       NULL AS `routine_param_list`,
      '' AS `routine_returns`,
       CONCAT(
        'Algorithm: ',
        `information_schema`.`VIEWS`.`ALGORITHM`,
        CHAR(13),
        CHAR(10),
        CHAR(13),
        CHAR(10),
        `information_schema`.`VIEWS`.`VIEW_DEFINITION`
      ) AS `routine_body`,
      '' AS `routine_comment`

    FROM
      (
        `information_schema`.`tables`
        LEFT JOIN `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`VIEWS`
          ON (
            `information_schema`.`VIEWS`.`TABLE_NAME` = `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_NAME`
          )
      )
    WHERE `information_schema`.`tables`.`TABLE_TYPE` = 'VIEW'
   )
    
    ) AS T
    
--   where routine_name = 'MyRoutine'
--    and routine_type = 'MyRouitineType'
```

**A typical routine that uses a variable**

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_known_as_name(the_member_id  int) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET latin1
    COMMENT 'returns the known as name if there is one, otherwise the forename'
BEGIN
    declare name_to_use VARCHAR(50);

     select
     IFNULL(member_known_as, member_fn_1) from member 
     where member_id = the_member_id
     into name_to_use ;
     return name_to_use ;
END
```

Comment: in mysql 8.0.23 this gives an error, also we need a [mre] to understand which result you expect excatly

Comment: It works in my version.  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'; results in MySQL version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-cll-lve;    innodb_version 10.3.27. Hence what I provided is a MRE (I copies the sql from my DBMS immediately after executing it so that I was sure it worked and pasted it into the post)

Comment: mariadb is **not** equal to mysql and also add which result you actually want

Comment: I've altered the tags just in case. As far as the result I want I can't really say as I don't know if the variables are held in a field of a system table, and so I don't know what field I'm looking for, or is I need to parse the definition SQL, if so how. I'll add an example of a definition that uses a variable though.